# Backwards tab-to-tab-stop?

Tags: indentation

The `tab-to-tab-stop` command moves the point to the next tabstop; I can't find an equivalent to move to the previous tabstop and `tab-to-tab-stop` doesn't accept a universal argument to reverse direction.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, looking at the source for `tab-to-tab-stop`,

```el
(defun tab-to-tab-stop ()
  (interactive)
  (and abbrev-mode (= (char-syntax (preceding-char)) ?w)
       (expand-abbrev))
  (let ((nexttab (indent-next-tab-stop (current-column))))
    (delete-horizontal-space t)
    (indent-to nexttab)))
```

it would only need to accept an optional prefix argument to pass to `indent-next-tab-stop` in order to achieve the requested bidirectionality, like so:

```el
(defun my-tab-to-tab-stop (&optional prev)
  "Like `tab-to-tab-stop', but toggle direction with prefix."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((nexttab (indent-next-tab-stop (current-column) prev)))
    (delete-horizontal-space t)
    (indent-to nexttab)))
```

I think the function is simple enough that you can redefine/rebind it yourself as I have shown (I left out the `abbrev-mode` stuff because I don't think it makes sense to expand things when indenting backwards).

You could also look into submitting this as a feature request (I am not familiar with the process).

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` for feature requests.